# Using C Functions in C++ Using extern "C"

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, g++

Iam trying to access two of my C functions in a Cpp code using extern "C". I am using it as follows :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstdio>


extern "C"
{
#include "pltfrm.h"
#include "xil_printf.h"

}



int main()
{
    init_platform();

    print("Hello World\n\r");
    print("Successfully ran Hello World application");
    cleanup_platform();
    return 0;
}
```

Functions `"init_platform"` and `"cleanup_platform"` are declared inside `"pltfrm.h"`

Iam getting "Undefined reference to" error on both functions.What am i doing wrong? iam compiling using eclipse build project option for c++ empty project template.

Comment: The keyword here is *declared* as opposed to *defined*. You are most probably not linking them. Unless you show exactly how you are compiling the code, we can't say much.

Comment: Are the functions in the modules compiled as `c`? Either you don't link them, or they are compiled as `cpp` functions with mangled names, which would also cause an `undefined reference` linker error because the names wont match.

Comment: I initially removed [tag:eclipse] and [tag:g++] tags, but the answer to your question depends on how do you compile your project. Do you use Eclipse project configuration, make, CMake or G++ directly?

Comment: C++ has native support for C code. The `extern "C"` in your case is surplus, it's needed only if C code is accessing C++ functions, not vice versa.

Comment: The conventional way to use headers in both languages is to add conditional `extern "C"` wrappers in the headers.

Comment: @molbdnilo I never encountered this convention, could you provide some respectable source for this statement?

Comment: @Gotiasits Look at your own system headers, or any library that's usable in both C and C++ and wasn't written by a novice.

Comment: @molbdnilo Any header in specific? For example OP uses `<stdio.h>` and `<stdlib.h>` which do not contain `extern C` for my local configuration.

Answer (score 0):

That message comes from the linking step, when all source files are compiled and the linker tries to connect all functions to the function calls.

You probably need to link to some library or add the source files, for the c-headers you added, to your project.

Comment: I used cpp project template in eclipse and added my .c and .h files in source and Compiling. I am not compiling c files seperately. Iam new to eclipse so i dont know how to change its compilation

Comment: Ok, havent used eclipses project in a while. Does this help? https://dzone.com/articles/how-add-existing-files-eclipse

Answer (score 0):

@Gotiasits  Answer was helpful in this case.I removed extern C and it seems native support is there. Will run the executbale in target and check